# Add query params to *.ts urls and *.m3u8 urls inside his playlist.m3u8 - iOS

Tags: ios, avfoundation, http-live-streaming

I need to add token as query parameter to *.ts urls  and *.m3u8 urls inside his playlist.m3u8

Is there any way to do this?

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31727139/avplayer-making-extraneous-http-request-prior-to-playback-of-hls-aes-encrypted), but not working as expected

Comment: Not working? WHat's your code?

Comment: here it is creating the custom playlist by hardcoding the file content. But I cannot do such way

Comment: And I have an intermediate m3u8 file for the bandwidth. So how the bandwidth selection will work?